# html_entity_decode not working

Tags: php, html, arrays, decode

I'm having an issue with the html_entity_decode function.

It's very strange because when I `echo` the string under this function it prints everything as i should but when I put the decoded string as an object value in an array, the function does not work anymore.

```
$body = substr(html_entity_decode($request->editor2), 0, 100);
```

I've even tried :

```
$body = substr(html_entity_decode($request->editor2, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), 0, 100);
```

Every thing so far is ok when I do :

```
echo $body;
```

But when I try it like this :

```
return $load = array('title' => $request->title,'body' => $body);
```

The string stored in `$body` is still encoded.

Does anyone have any idea why this is not working ?

EDIT 
this is the string under echo before return :

```
MINISTRI I MIRËQËNIES SOCIALE DHE RINISË,  Z. BLENDI KLOSI NË
```

this is the array I'm trying to return .

```
{"title":"N\u00eb p\u00ebrpjekjen e vazhdueshme p\u00ebr mbrojtjen e f\u00ebmij\u00ebve","body":"<p style=\"text-align:justify\"><em>MINISTRI I MIR\u00cbQ\u00cbNIES SOCIALE DHE RINIS\u00cb,\u00a0 Z. BLENDI KLOSI N\u00cb"}
```

Comment: can you post the string, please?

Comment: How does it look if you put `echo $body;` right before your `return` statement?

Comment: So you want to decode the unicode characters? Unicode characters and HTML entities are not the same

Comment: Resolved the issue by using strip_tag...thanks for the replies